# RecyclerView doesn't animate an item when it initially appears, only when it is recycled again

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, android-animation

I have a `TranslateAnimation` for a view inside an item of a `RecyclerView.Adapter`. The animation should be applied to a specific list item when it initially appears, but it only works when you scroll back and the item is recycled again.

My guess is that it has something to do with the RecyclerView's lifecycle, but I couldn't figure out what's causing the animation to not start.

```
class mAdapter(items: List<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<mAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

  private var mPosition = 0

  // The animation will be applied to the first item
  override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    if (position == mPosition){
      return 1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }

  override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)

        // Animate the view inside the item
        if (holder.itemViewType == 1){
            holder.animateItem()
        }
    }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)

        // Animate the view inside the item
        if (holder.itemViewType == 1){
          holder.animateItem()
        }
    }

  inner class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val picture: ImageView? = view.findViewById(R.id.picture)       

    fun animateItem(){
      val itemWidth: Float = itemView.width.toFloat()
      val animator = TranslateAnimation(-itemWidth, 0f, 0f, 0f)

      animator.repeatCount = 0
      animator.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f)
      animator.duration = 700
      animator.fillAfter = true

      background?.animation = animator
      background?.startAnimation(animator)
    }  

  }

}
```

If I log a message inside `animateItem` it will appear when the RecycleView loads but it will not animate until I scroll down and up.

#### Answer

As [NSimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4232337/nsimon) pointed out, the solution is to write a `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
  holder.itemView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener{
    holder.animateItem()
  }
}
```

Comment: What could be happening is that the first time, the items are not "rendered" yet, which means your animation is playing, but itemWidth = 0, hence you don't see it. Try hardcoding itemWidth and see if it plays. If so, you might want to wrap your animate() code inside a onGlobalLayout() or similar (ie, wait for the view to be rendered, then apply the animation)

Comment: Thanks! `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` did the job! Would you write this as an answer for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your first animation was actually playing properly.
However, the first time it was invoked, the View had not been fully layered on screen. Therefore, `itemView.width.toFloat()` was returning 0, and you were animating from 0 to 0.

The quick solution is to encapsulate the launch of the animation inside a GlobalLayoutListener (which is the system telling you that the view has been layered).

Something like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
  holder.itemView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener{
    holder.animateItem()
  }
}
```

Bare in mind though, that you should remove the globalLayoutListener once you've started the animation (otherwise it stays there forever and will keep triggering if/when something happens to the view). So a better approach would be to create a helper function like this one:

```
inline fun <T: View> T.afterMeasured(crossinline f: T.() -> Unit) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {    
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {    
            if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {    
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)    
                f()    
            }    
        }    
    })   
}
```

and call it inside onBindViewHolder like so:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
  holder.itemView.afterMeasured{
    holder.animateItem()
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that and I added a class variable to the `ViewHolder` to know if it is still animating, not sure if I should also remove the listener

Comment: Usually removing the listener after it's been fired once is the easiest/most reusable way to go. But hey, if your solution works too, fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. The `ViewHolder` is only recycled sometime after its initial use. Don't do the animation in `onViewRecycled`. You might try `onBindViewHolder` instead, although I'm not sure the exact timing you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but the animation doesn't start until the view is refreshed. Do you know  how to start the animation when it initially appear?